# Set a selected value for a DropDownList on page post back/page load?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor page which has the following code:

```
@{
     var listItems = new List<ListItem>
     {
          new ListItem { Text = "Select a Prefix", Value = "None" },
          new ListItem { Text = "a", Value = "a" },
          new ListItem { Text = "b", Value = "b" },
          new ListItem { Text = "c", Value = "c" },
     };
 }
 @Html.DropDownList("DropDownListOperationsPrefix", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"), new { onchange = "GetOperationPrefix()", @class = "someclass"})
```

How do I set a selected value for the dropdownlist when it posts back? Basically, preserve user selection on postback of page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
new ListItem { Text = "a", Value = "a", Selected=true }
```

on the required item.

Comment: If I have a value from Session that I want to set as selected value, then  what should I do? Like I said, I want to preserve the user selection on page postback.